# How to filter only additional character with Regular Expression in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have written the following Regular Expression to filter additional character in Java:

```
this.myTextField.matches("[\\W]*");
```

The Problem is, that this kind of expression filters additional character and mutated vowels.

I need an expression which filters only additional character like `<>!"§$%()=}{` and must be excepted mutated vowels like `öäüß`.

Comment: Try replacing `[<>!"§$%()=}{]` with empty string

Comment: Use `[^\\wöäü]*` and add more characters as necessary to the character class. Are you sure you need to match vowels only? `\\P{L}*` will match all characters other than Unicode letters - maybe you need that. Or `[\\P{L}\\P{M}]*` to also match non-diacritics.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `[\\W]*` with `[^\\p{L}]*`.

The `\W` means anything which is not within `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, this includes unicode letters.

The `\p{L}`, as shown [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) is a character set which denotes *any kind of letter from any language*. Thus, `[^\p{L}]` denotes any character which is not a letter in any language.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
String dirtyString = " This*is#a*&very_dirty&String";
System.out.print(dirtyString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]"," ")); // Replace all with " "
                                                               // except a-z, A-Z, 0-9 
                                                               // and space.

// prints "This is a  very dirty String"
```